# Flutter installs SDK Tools again, even though they exists

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-sdk-tools, command-line-tool

```
[   +1 ms] All projects evaluated.
[+1797 ms] Selected primary task 'assembleDebug' from project :
[+15200 ms] Parsing legacy package: C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools
[+1099 ms] Parsing legacy package: C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools
[ +500 ms] Parsing legacy package: C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools
[+15000 ms] Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform-Tools in C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\licenses
[+3699 ms] License for package Android SDK Platform-Tools accepted.
[+1000 ms] Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 34.0.0)".
[ +900 ms] Warning: Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@5f80ebe9" (platform-tools) should be installed in
[   +1 ms] "C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\platform-tools" but
[  +20 ms] it already exists.
[   +1 ms] Installing in "C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\platform-tools-4" instead.
[+47475 ms] "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 34.0.0)" ready.
[   +1 ms] Installing Android SDK Platform-Tools in C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\platform-tools-4
[  +98 ms] "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 34.0.0)" complete.
[+9100 ms] "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 34.0.0)" finished.
[        ] Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\licenses
[        ] License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 accepted.
[        ] Preparing "Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)".
[ +105 ms] Warning: Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@b2d2115" (patcher;v4) should be installed in
[   +1 ms] "C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\patcher\v4" but
[        ] it already exists.
[        ] Installing in "C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\patcher\v4-5" instead.
[+20388 ms] "Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" ready.
[   +1 ms] Installing SDK Patch Applier v4 in C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\patcher\v4-5
[        ] "Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" complete.
[        ] "Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" finished.
[        ] Checking the license for package Android Emulator in C:\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\licenses
[        ] License for package Android Emulator accepted.
[        ] Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 32.1.11)".`
```

So i have installed flutter without android studio using cmdline-tools
everything works perfectly just when you create a new app and run it for first time this process starts and installs everything again.